# Bootstrap select combobox and ngRepeat options not working

Tags: angularjs, combobox, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-select

I am trying to show tags in a Bootstrap select combobox. However, ng-repeat is not populating the options. After some research, I believe I need to write a directive for this, because Bootstrap takes the options and makes a list out of them before Angular adds the options. But I don't know what writing a directive involves.

```
<select class="combobox form-control" ng-model = "tags.repeatSelect">
<option ng-repeat = "tag in tags.tagNames" value = "{{tag.string}}"> {{tag.string}} </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem.

```
 <select data-ng-model="modelValue" class="form-control" data-ng-options="item.string for item in tags.tagNames">
 </select>
```